# Why arent the vertices snapping to the head

Tags: modeling, vertices, retopology

I need to retopolgyz my head but the vertices aren't snapping to the head[image]

Answer (score 2):

Next to each modifier name are some options determining display.

[image: View Options Highlighted]

The four vertex shape toggles visibility in edit mode (see above that the shrinkwrap isn't even visible). The triangle toggles whether it actually deforms in edit mode. Turn it on and your problem is solved.

[image: Editing on Shape]

If you've never done this before I'd also recommend turning the setting on when working with mirror modifiers as it lets you select vertices on either side of the mirror.